# No download csv file if error using ngCsv

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

I am using ngCsv. I have the following problem. The content of csv file is the result of a promise. All ok, but when ocurred a error, the csv download any way. I need that if exist error, the csv file not begin download.

My code

```js
$scope.getCsv = function()
    {
        var body = mlService.getMatrixFromCsv($scope.p.fileContent, $scope.features, $scope.p.head);
        if(body[0].length != $scope.features.length || body[0][1] == undefined)
        {
            $scope.page_error = "csv file It does not correspond with model";
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.page_error = "";
            }, 10000);
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.csvheader = $scope.features;
            $scope.csvheader.push("predict");
            $scope.csvContent = $http.post(mlService.getMlMultitenancyOrigin()+ '/python/predict', {"model":$scope.params[2], "value": body}).then(function(result){
                var data = mlService.buildMatrixCsvFromResponse(body, $scope.features, JSON.parse(result.data));
                return data;
            });
            return $scope.csvContent;
        }
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary r" type="button" ng-csv="getCsv()" filename="predcit.csv" csv-header="csvheader"><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Predict</button>
```

Comment: this is very confusing and I think you are confusing yourself naming variables that refer to promises with `content` in the variable name. Is `getMatrixFromCsv()` asynchronous? Note that you don't return anything in first condition. Show all relevant code

Comment: getMatrixFromCsv() is a function in a service file. It is not asynchronous. in the first condiction I not return, only update the variable page_error. I can return any thing in this case, but also donwload csv

Comment: Ok, then not clear what error you are talking about

Comment: in particular if there is any way that using ngcsv the file not download  if a certain condition is met

Comment: sure, don't request it